# defining custom model class in spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I currently have a mapping method in spring with the following signature:

```
@RequestMapping("/checkout.action")
protected String checkout(ModelMap map) { ... return "logicalViewName"; }
```

I would like to define my custom map class that extends `ModelMap` and have that passed to my method instead. Is there a simple way to do this? I was going to replace the code that creates the initial map object but wasn't able to find out where that is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no simple way to achieve this. You will need to alter Spring's internals to replace the implementation of `ModelMap`.

If you use Spring 3.1 or later, the class injecting the `ModelMap` is `org.springframework.web.method.annotation.MapMethodProcessor`.